# Does NW adapter powers off before Windows shutdown script is triggered?

Tags: windows, powershell, shutdown-script

In my usecase i need to send API call upon Windows machine shutdown/reboot.

The script i created works as expected from the PowerShell console, but not when defined in `gpedit.msc`'s *shutdown scripts* location.

I am assuming this is because WiFi adapter somehow gets down before the script gets executed. Added some debug prints and seems that it is a corect observation.

To prove it more i re-defined the same script in *user login scripts* location - and it worked as expected indeed.

My question is whether it is really correct that a WiFi adapter disconnects before the shutdown script steps into the process, and if yes - is there any way to outsmart it with PowerShell script?

*(My theory is that trapping/delaying a WiFi adapter in a shutdown could adress the case, but even if i knew how to do that i smell the same issue here - the adapter will go down before the trap pops up...)*

EDIT: the thing is definitely with the adapter power on shutdown call. If i define the User Logoff script - the script works even if i do reboot or shut down.

Comment: you could prove your theory by writing the available/visible network adapters to a temporary file in the shutdown script.

Comment: @GuentherSchmitz - it might be a good test, but is there still a way to delay the adapter powerdown process it if this is the case?

Comment: that i don't know - sorry - that's why i suggested to figure it out using some (more) tests.

Comment: @faceless - would you please fix your title? the misspelling and the lack of a sensible end to the title make it disconcerting at best. [*grin*]

Comment: @faceless - you are most welcome ... and thanks back to you for fixing it! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

So despite i didn't find a way to intercept the NW adapter power supply on shutdown (as well as no comprehensive technical documentation of this feature), i definitely found out a way to acheive **my usecase** - define the `user logoff scripts` instead of `shutdown scripts`.